# How can I remove the spaces in html tags if tags only contain whitespace? using HTMLAgility C#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```html
<p style="text-align:right;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:0pt;text-indent:0%;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:11pt;"> </p>
```

here you can see the space inside the p tag,  want to remove this space from the whole html document.
I am using HTMLAgility pack to remove few HTML characters already. Not sure how should I remove this whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to do that, searching for all paragraph elements that have only spaces as its inner text value, replacing these paragraph elements with empty paragraphs.

```
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(
@"<body>
    <p>      </p>
    <span>My span text ! </span>
    <p> </p>
</body>");

            //Using HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors.NetCore
            var ps = doc.QuerySelectorAll("p").Where(p => p.InnerText.ToCharArray().All(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));

            for(var i = 0; i < ps.Count(); i++)
            {
                var p = ps.ElementAt(i);
                var newP = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<p></p>");
                p.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newP, p);
            }

            doc.Save("demo.html");
```